# Doesn't CasperJS support redirects with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

On a site that I'm scraping there is a form, which is submitted with JavaScript. After the button is clicked, an Ajax request is sent and after response is received redirect happens with location.replace...

```
$("#send").click ( function () {
    var vaaal=encodeURIComponent($("#questionask").val());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/__ajax_post.php',
            data: 'text='+vaaal+'&news=1',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
              if ($(xml).find("error").text()==1) {
               $.unblockUI();
                alert ("error");
                return false;
              }
              if ($(xml).find("num").text()) {
                window.location.replace('/question/'+$(xml).find("num").text());
                return false;
              }
            }
        });
  });
```

After that we get redirected to site-name/question/2098147 url and page loads with data that I need.

I use this code:

```
spooky.start('http://sprosi-putina.ru/', function fillForm() {
    this.fill('form[name="askmore"]', { questionask: 'fdgs'}, false);
});

spooky.then(function clickSend() {
    this.mouse.click("#send");
});

spooky.then(function readAnswer() {
    this.emit('answerisready', this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('.answer').textContent;
    }));
});

spooky.run();
```

but after PhantomJS clicks on the button, something goes wrong:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 4 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://sprosi-putina.ru/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://sprosi-putina.ru/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://sprosi-putina.ru/"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20160601/r20151006/zrt_lookup.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4784365547122494&output=html&h=90&slotname=2587861763&adk=581066870&w=728&lmt=1465063498&ea=0&flash=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsprosi-putina.ru%2F&wgl=0&dt=1465074178527&bdt=301&idt=323&shv=r20160601&cbv=r20151006&saldr=sb&correlator=2508528726017&frm=20&ga_vid=1561585347.1465074179&ga_sid=1465074179&ga_hid=1525633997&ga_fc=0&pv=2&iag=0&icsg=1018&dssz=7&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=180&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1024&u_ah=768&u_aw=1024&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&dff=verdana&dfs=16&adx=0&ady=0&biw=400&bih=300&eid=20040014%2C575144605%2C4087318&oid=3&rx=0&eae=4&fc=216&pc=1&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1024%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C400%2C300&vis=1&rsz=%7C%7C%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u1&pfx=0&fu=1040&bc=1&ifi=1&dtd=418, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step fillForm 2/4 http://sprosi-putina.ru/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step fillForm 2/4: done in 2384ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/5 http://sprosi-putina.ru/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/5: done in 2405ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 1000ms.
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="askmore"]'
attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="askmore"]'
[debug] [remote] Set "questionask" field value to fdgs
Set "questionask" field value to fdgs
[info] [phantom] Step clickSend 4/5 http://sprosi-putina.ru/ (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://sprosi-putina.ru/, type=LinkClicked, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[info] [phantom] Step clickSend 4/5: done in 3458ms.
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://sprosi-putina.ru/"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/html/r20160601/r20151006/zrt_lookup.html, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4784365547122494&output=html&h=90&slotname=2587861763&adk=581066870&w=728&lmt=1465063500&ea=0&flash=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsprosi-putina.ru%2F&wgl=0&dt=1465074180587&bdt=15&idt=9&shv=r20160601&cbv=r20151006&saldr=sb&correlator=2171302658049&frm=20&ga_vid=1561585347.1465074179&ga_sid=1465074181&ga_hid=862582667&ga_fc=0&pv=2&iag=0&icsg=1018&dssz=7&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=180&u_his=1&u_java=0&u_h=768&u_w=1024&u_ah=768&u_aw=1024&u_cd=32&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&dff=verdana&dfs=16&adx=0&ady=0&biw=400&bih=300&eid=20040014%2C575144605%2C828064225&oid=3&rx=0&eae=4&fc=216&pc=1&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1024%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C400%2C300&vis=1&rsz=%7C%7C%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u1&pfx=0&fu=1040&bc=1&ifi=1&dtd=31, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step readAnswer 5/5 http://sprosi-putina.ru/ (HTTP 200)
null
[info] [phantom] Step readAnswer 5/5: done in 3681ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 5 steps in 3698ms
```

As you can see from logs instead of going to `/response/number` we go to some google ads first and then end up on the same page from where we started - home page (http://sprosi-putina.ru/ ).
Can't CasperJS handle JavaScript redirects properly or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS doesn't pick up on the redirect, because it happens much later than the click. If you have a dynamic page, then you should use appropriate `wait*` functions such as `waitForSelector`:

```
spooky.waitForSelector('.answer', function readAnswer() {
    this.echo(this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('.answer').textContent;
    }));
});
```

Comment: it's not that. [error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/7d831bffb4da5cc044501f81cc9f9da3) works for me with CasperJS 1.1-beta5 and PhantomJS 2.1.1. I get the ".answer" output

Comment: Could you please send me all the debugging logs that CasperJS and PhantomJS output while execution

Comment: I've added the output to the link. The encoding is a different issue. Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: It finally worked when I added viewportSize : { width: 1200, height: 1200 }, setting to the casper options object. Strange...

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why that was necessary. Oh well, every page is different and PhantomJS has many quirks.